# Jekyll not building or seeing collection

Tags: jekyll

I can not seem to get Jekyll to recognize that a collection exists!

I have my folder structure like so

```
_posts
_includes
_layouts
_sass
_site
_portfolio
assets
index.html
```

_portfolio is the collection

I have it in my _config.yml file as so

```
colletions:
  portfolio:
    output: true
```

And I'm trying to show it in a list here (this snippet is from my default layout which is being used in my index.html)

```
{% for item in site.portfolio %}
        <a href="{{ item.url | relative_url }}" class="portfolio-item-link"> 
            <div class="portfolio-item" style="background: url('{{ site.url }}/assets/img/{{ item.image }}'); background-size: cover; background-position: center;">
                <h1 class="portfolio-item-title">{{ item.title }}</h1>
            </div>
        </a>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is Jekyll isn't even adding anything to the collection! If I do `{{ site.portfolio | inspect }}` it returns nil. I've also tried generating the site on my Ubuntu system (my current system is windows). If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

So I misspelled "collections" in my _config.yml file. Don't do that. It works now.